# Rails conditionally apply class pending answer with Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I've never done a conditional apply of a class so I'm at a bit of a loss.

```
- if @something.elses.all.count > 5
 .this-client
  - @something.elses.all.each do |thing|
   = image_tag thing.photo, class: 'align-middle'
- else
 .this-other-client
  - @something.elses.all.each do |thing|
   = image_tag thing.photo, class: 'align-middle'
```

RuboCop really hates that I have the same thing in both conditions and I get that. So how do I apply a conditional class based on the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
div class=(@something.elses.all.count > 5 ? 'this-client' : 'this-other-client')
  - @something.elses.all.each do |thing|
   = image_tag thing.photo, class: 'align-middle'
```

Also, it's un-Rails-like to perform a query like that in a view. If there's another way to get that count you should look into it

Comment: I was literally just thinking "hey this should probably just go in a helper"